# Scala pattern matching for vararg

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm just trying to do some hands on on scala and tried to implement List.concat function on my own . Here is the code

```
  def concat[A](lists : Traversable[A]*):List[A]={
    println("concat called")
    lists match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case x :: Nil => (x :\ List.empty[A])((elem,list)=> elem::list)
      case x:: xs => (x :\ concat(xs:_*))((elem,list)=> elem :: list)
    }
  }
```

However when i try to call this method like

```
concat(List(1,2,3),List(2,3,4),List(4,5,6),List(6,7,8))
```

I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: WrappedArray(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(4, 5, 6), List(6, 7, 8)) (of class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef)
```

Can someone explain what i did wrong here ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Varags is a `Seq` and you can match on it like on a `Seq`, not like on a list. Here is an example:

```
@ a(1, 2, 3) 
res1: Seq[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
@ def a(x: Int*) = x match {
                  case Seq() => "empty"
                  case Seq(a) => s"single $a"
                  case Seq(a, as @ _*) => s"multiple: $a, $as"
                } 
defined function a
@ a(1, 2, 3, 4) 
res3: String = "multiple: 1, WrappedArray(2, 3, 4)"
@ a(1, 2) 
res4: String = "multiple: 1, WrappedArray(2)"
@ a(1) 
res5: String = "single 1"
```

Doing such matching on `Nil` and `x :: xs` usually means, that you can simply use `foldLeft`, which does just that.

```
def concat[A](lists: Traversable[A]*): List[A] =
    lists.foldLeft(List.empty[A])(_ ++ _)
```

And note, that matching on `Nil` and `x :: xs`, where `xs` can be `Nil`, is enough. Your second `case` can be simply removed.

Just look at those:

```
case Nil => Nil
case x :: Nil => (x :\ List.empty[A])(_ :: _)
case x :: xs  => (x :\ concat(xs:_*))(_ :: _)
```

last two are the same. If in third case `xs == Nil` then in place of `concat(xs:_*)` you will get your `Nil`, which is same as `List.empty[A]` (if type is infered correctly).

Answer (score 3):

`Nil` is a `List`:

```
scala> Nil
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()
```

However, Scala wraps all variadic parameters into a `Seq` (`WrappedArray` implements `Seq`), that is why you get the `MatchError`. You could rewrite your function in the following way:

```
scala>   def concat[A](lists : Traversable[A]*):List[A]={
     |     lists match {
     |       case Seq() => Nil
     |       case x +: Seq() => (x :\ List.empty[A])((elem,list)=> elem::list)
     |       case x +: xs => (x :\ concat(xs:_*))((elem,list)=> elem :: list)
     |     }
     |   }
concat: [A](lists: Traversable[A]*)List[A]

scala> concat(List(1), List(2), List(3))
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

You could also simplify your function using `flatMap`:

```
scala> def concat[A](lists: Traversable[A]*): List[A] = {
     |     lists.flatMap(x => x).toList
     | }
concat: [A](lists: Traversable[A]*)List[A]

scala> concat(List(1), List(2), List(3))
res16: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: He could as well simplify it doing `lists.toList.flatten` but this probably wasn't the point here :)

Comment: Sure, that is why I mentioned it at the end of the post :)

Comment: `lists.flatMap(x => x)` == `lists.flatten`

Comment: Of course. And also it is same to what OP implemented. That is the point: we are showing different ways of doing the same thing, at least conceptually, because all those implementations are totally different in scala library.